# Strange activity on Wingate Proxy

Tags: networking, firewall, gateway

I noticed some strange network activity on my network last night. I've never seen anything like it. It appeared as though public ip addresses were connnecting outward from my private network. It only started randomly happening after 9pm.

They were making connections to random sites like google.pl and spickipedia.com. See examples below.

AV scan picked up nothing. I fixed the issue by restoring a backup. The only software I installed since that backup was Spiceworks Desktop and Network Monitor. Would that be the cause? - If so, seems strange why routable IPs would show in my network activity and be connecting to the URLs they were.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Running Windows Server 2012 R2 and Wingate 8.

01/03/2016  23:47:37    unknown 320300  766 87.206.204.157  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36 GET htt://www.spickipedia.com/index.php/tipps-a-tricks/2730-sony-xperia-z1-compact-mp3-klingelton-verwenden -   200 611 11337   http    htt://www.spickipedia.com/

01/03/2016  21:32:46    unknown 309777  2281    94.23.198.128   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4    GET htt://www.google.pl/    gws_rd=cr,ssl   200 504 26339   http    -

Btw the above are missing the p's from http due to need a higher rep to post more than 2 links

See the full spreadsheet here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfkkbi1slc9exic/20160301_000_WWW%20Proxy%20Server%202.txt?dl=0

Thanks in advance,

Z

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have WinGate proxies bound unsecured to external interfaces that are reachable from the internet.  If you do, then you will be picked up by port scanners, and unless you require authentication, used as an open proxy.  Specifically it looks like the WWW proxy is accepting connections from the Internet and performing proxy requests for those clients.

If you haven't already done so, I'd recommend getting in touch with WinGate support (email support@wingate.com) to resolve this.

By default, WinGate takes several steps to avoid being open to the internet, but it can depend on configuration of other systems in your network (e.g. if you have a firewall that forwards all traffic to the WinGate server on a private network)

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate